# How to save the HTML of a website

Tags: file-manager

I'm curious, how do you save a webpage that you know will be taken down in the near future? Is there a way to cache the webpage that is being served to you, or should I copy and paste all the involved files to my computer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This type of question is better suited for [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the most simple solution of saving the webpage from your browser (typically with <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd>, there are many apps to download all the website files to your computer, so can navegate them offline, even if the website is down. Apps like [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget) will do the job.

Or if the website was "popular" enough there is a high chance of it already being cached or saved by [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) or Search Engines caches (You can take a look at an older version of a webpage at http://cachedpage.co/ (**disclaimer:** I did that).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't an owner of the domain or hosting account are you? Otherwise you'd use FTP client to download it.

If you want to save a public web page then:
1. File / Save as "Page Source", "Web page - HTML only", "Web Page - complete" or "Web Archive" and other options available in the web browser.
2. A copy of the page also works.

In some web browsers (Mozila/FireFox for example) you could go, right-click, choose "View Page Source" and then save the HTML code.

Safari has a very nice feature "Export as PDF" that allows the user to save a way page as PDF file.